# Superclass mismatch for class in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm working on project that requires different classes to have the same name like this:

lib/command.rb

```
class Command
end
```

lib/command/group.rb

```
class Command
  class Group < Command
  end
end
```

lib/command/group/add.rb

```
class Command
  class Group
    class Add < Group
      # do something
    end
  end
end
```

and lib/group.rb

```
class Group
  # do something
end
```

Rakefile

```
task :reload do
  Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/lib/**/*.rb'].each{ |file| load file }
end

task default: 'reload'
```

The first three classes behaves like a helper, and last class is the model.

When I run `Rakefile` to load all classes, it will raise the `TypeError: superclass mismatch for class Group` indeed.

How should I solve it without renaming one of the `Group` classes? Is it possible?

Comment: No way; the above is perfectly loaded. The issue should be somewhere else. You might try to copy-paste the above into a separated file and try to `ruby file.rb` it.

Comment: This means that you opened the same `Group` class twice, but used a different superclass (`< Superclass`).

Comment: Try `class ::Group` for the second class. Is the result same?

Comment: Alternatively loading the group.rb class before command/group.rb should stop the parser from trying to be clever and reopen an existing class.

Comment: @sawa doesn't work, it's still error.

Comment: @rizkyduut try to provide a [mcve] – your current example code doesn't raise any errors.

Comment: @Stefan aw thanks, I didn't try the code before. I've edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lib/command/group/add.rb` may get loaded before `lib/command/group.rb`. Hence in the latter, it appears as if you try to change which class `Group` inherits from.

The band aid solution would be to point to the same subclass in all files. Aka in `lib/command/group/add.rb`, you should add `< Command`.

The real solution should be to never use a class/module for namespacing and attach functionality to it.

---

<sup>This issue was raised in Euruko 2016 and Matz said they might consider a special keyword for it. [Citation needed]</sup>

Comment: I wasn't aware that Ruby allows to reopen a class without specifying its superclass. Is that considered a feature?

Comment: @Stefan yep. This is the only difference between no explicit inheritance and `< Object` AFAIK.

Comment: Attempting to reopen it via `module` on the other hand fails with a `TypeError`.

Comment: @Stefan, yep. That was the actual issue raised in Euruko, not the inheritance one. But as is, it kind of makes sense. Using `class` in one place and `module` in another is a direct contradiction (you say the constant is two different things). Reopening a class isn't though - you aren't saying that it now inherits from `Object`. It's just that if it wasn't defined before `Object` is the default.

Comment: @ndn If I want to keep the inheritance like above `Command < Group < Add` how should I design it then? Is there any reference for it?

Comment: @rizkyduut just put them all in a `Commands` module. Aka all of them will just be nested in `Commands` and everything there can inherit from whatever you want. Don't nest `Group` under `Command` and `Add` under `Group`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for providing further code. It's now clear that there is an error here. You define `Command::Group` twice, but only one of them inherits from `Command`

lib/command/group.rb

```
class Command
  class Group < Command
  end
end
```

lib/command/group/add.rb

```
class Command
  class Group # missing inheritance
    class Add < Group
      # do something
    end
  end
end
```